# How to use tornado authentication in a django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, tornado

I use a combination of **Django** and **Tornado** for my website. Tornado has a wonderful
authentication system and I would like to use it in the django views. Unfortunately I get an `AttributeError`.

**How can I use Tornado authentication in my Django views?**

**View**

```
import tornado.web
from django import shortcuts

@tornado.web.authenticated
def testpage(request):
    return shortcuts.render(request, 'web/templates/index.html')
```

**Error message**

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'current_user'
```

Django is connected to Tornado through `WSGIContainer`:

```
def main():
    static_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static')


    assert os.path.isdir(static_path), static_path

    wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
    django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())

    tornado_app = tornado.web.Application([],static_path=static_path,)
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)

    server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you use an alternative for tornado authenticated in Django. You can use django decorators, such as `login_required` (source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Because Tornado offers a very simple support for Facebook, Google, Twitter and OAuth2 authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tornado.auth` module goes through the openid/oauth flow, but at the end of that process all it does is call back to your code where you probably set a cookie.  You read that cookie in Tornado with `get_current_user`, but that's specific to the Tornado RequestHandler interface.  To use this cookie from django you'll need to read the cookie yourself (see the tornado.web.decode_signed_value function, assuming you set the cookie with set_secure_cookie).  You can either find the right place in the django framework to do this, in which case you may be able to use django's `login_required` decorator, or you can just do it in your django handler in which case you'll need to redirect to the login form on your own.